# Argument type '{directives: any[];}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'

Tags: ionic-framework, parameters, arguments

I am getting this error:

> Argument type '{directives: any[];}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Image of error]

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: its ionic framework

Comment: Screenshot is in the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDVmu.png

Comment: Thanks, the tag will allow experts in that area to see your question.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: ANd Thank you so Much dear for good suggestion <3

Comment: Sorry, ionic-framework is not my area of expertise.